# How to fill the faces from vector file

Tags: faces

I have design in illustrator and exported in Autocad DXF format. And imported the file. Its in curve format so i have converted to mesh. After converting to mesh i Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill face and Selected the verts and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to fill. Its not working. Im getting different result compare with my original design.

[image]

**Original Design**

[image]

Result im getting from <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key

[image]

I want to fill reverse way. Any suggestion or Help. Thanks

Comment: have you considered cutting the shape into a plane inside illustrator and import that into blender?

Comment: @Sidar im not getting the fill face to cut plane in blender and reverse.

Comment: Not in blender, I mean have you tried cutting a plane  in illustrator to get the inverse? You can do boolean operations in ilustrator

Comment: @sidar the above image its made in illustrator. Why im not getting same result in Blender

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I'm asking have you tried doing the inverse in illustrator and import the inverse and see if that solves it? You can get the inverse by doing bool operations and cutting the shape into a plane.

Comment: @Sidar it work with the reverse as mention above but why not this file same as it is. Thanks for the other option

Comment: I don't know your setup but i'm assuming your little pieces are all seperate and not part of the outer edge. So it's not treated as one and blender can not generate the proper faces but only for the smaller pieces. Whereas if you cut into the plane you generate additional vertices which belong to the same connection.